# VB: grouping classes into namespaces

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, namespaces

In C# when we create a folder, all classes which go into that folder will fall under the folder name as their namespace. Alternatively using the `namespace` keyword we can define them manually. But in VB when I create a folder this is not done automatically. Lets say I wanna add an Entity Framework object and it falls in the default namespace. Then if there's a login table in the EF I can't have a window named as Login. this causes a lotta problem. How can change the namespace of the edmx file ? and prevent namespace collision in VB?

Comment: You can change the namespace of the edmx by left clicking the .edmx file (in the solution explorer) and then open the .edmx File Properties window; Modify the value of _Custom Tool Namespace_.  Note that, by default “Custom Tool Namespace” property will be empty, so the Designer.cs file’s namespace is the project default namespace.

Comment: @DavidTansey: It does not change the namespace

Answer (score 0):

VB.Net has something that 'we' call the `Root Namespace`. Where C# has a `default namespace`.

The big difference is that the `Root Namespace` is really the root and will be therefore always be added in front of everything you define in your code file.

C# however will use the default namespace to use this to add a `namespace` statement to your code file when you add it. It will also use the foldername to build up the complete namespace.

VB.Net does not need a namespace in the code file, allthough you can add one to create a C# like naming convention. If you would use this approach is advisable to clear out the `Root namespace` from the properties of your project and your back in control.

For most tools that generate code you can normally configure this in the properties of the custom tool that generated the code through the `custom tool namespace` property.  For entity framework you should change this by opening the properties of the `edmx` file and add something to the `custom tool namespace` property. This will be empty by default.

**BUT**:  The default T4 templates does not make use of the custom tool namespace. So you will need to edit all your tt templates (normally `YourModel.tt` and `YourModel.context.tt` to use a namespace. I have never been able to let the generator make use of the `custom tool namespace` property. I took the shortcut and changed this line the T4 templates:

```
Dim codeNamespace as String = code.VsNamespaceSuggestion()
```

to this:

```
Dim codeNamespace as String = "Your.Desired.Namespace"
```

Don't forget to set the solution explorer to `Show All files` in order to find the T4 templates.